# Sending someone Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode

I'd like to send another developer an Xcode project of mine to debug.  Are there any issues with security in doing so?  I.e. developer keys and such.  Form what I understand, the key will be in my keychain on my Mac, so the Xcode project folder should be fine to send.  Am I correct in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct. Compressing and sending your XCode project will not reveal any of your sensitive developer info, only plaintext passwords and such in your source code.

Answer (score 1):

You won't send any of your developer credentials, but you will be giving the developer the intellectual property that is contained in your project.

Comment: That's fine.  This is just a sample project that is a very stripped down version of my actual project.  Nothing confidential within the project code itself